# Why should I use both traits and services in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, traits

I have a simple question I am struggling to answer and I hope guys you can help me. So I am developing application on laravel. I wanted to make Controllers clear so I have complex queries inside Model classes itself (I don't want to use repositories). If I want some functionality that will be used for many models I put this functionality inside traits and use it whenever needed. So here is my question.. Do I need Service classes at all? Isn't Traits enough?

Comment: Kind of broad, depends on what you're doing with your models.  Eventually, having too many functions in a single model may prove to be hard to maintain.  The concept of 'God Objects' comes to mind.

Comment: It is totally depend on your functionality that what are you using inside trait function is it dependent on other services or not.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _specific_ programming issues, not discussion about should I / shouldn’t I-type questions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's say you have a method in a trait which requires a `Cat` model and a `Dog` model.  Each time you use that trait, you need to pass in an instance of `Cat` and an instance of `Dog` for it to do its work.

Eventually that's going to get tiring.  And what happens if you eventually add a feature and the trait now requires a `Bird` model?  Now you have a lot of code to modify just to start passing the `Bird` to the method in the trait each time you want to use it.

This is where a service class becomes very handy.  In the service class' constructor, you can inject the `User`, `Permission`, and `Role` model like so...

```
public function __construct(Cat $cat, Dog $dog, Bird $bird)
{
    $this->cat = $cat;
    $this->dog = $dog;
    $this->bird = $bird;
}
```

Then you can add a service provider to your app which instructs Laravel how to create this service class by passing in the appropriate models.  From there, you can have this service automatically injected into your controllers as you see fit where currently you are just using a trait for this.

What this means is if you ever needed to add a dependency, you only need to update one, possibly two files.  The service class itself to add additional items to the constructor and possibly the service provider.  All the controllers that are using this don't need to be updated to pass in those additional items to the constructor since that's handled by Laravel (more appropriately the IoC container).

This is also extremely beneficial for testing.  When injecting dependencies into a class, it's easier to just set up your testing environment to mock those dependencies rather than trying to build mocks on the fly to pass into the trait methods.  It's also more difficult to test a trait since something needs to `use` that trait in order for the trait's methods to be tested.

```
// we can use a service provider to tell laravel how to create this service (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers)
class PetService
{
    protected $cat;
    protected $dog;
    protected $bird;

    public function __construct(Cat $cat, Dog $dog, Bird $bird)
    {
        $this->cat = $cat;
        $this->dog = $dog;
        $this->bird = $bird;
    }

    public function doStuff()
    {
        //  does things with $this->cat, $this->dog, $this->bird
    }
}


class PetController
{
    // use PetTrait;

    protected $petService;

    // laravel will automatically create the PetService for us and pass it into the constructor when building this controller (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container)
    public function __construct(PetService $petService) 
    {
        $this->petService = $petService;
    }

    public function someControllerMethod()
    {
        // $this->doStuff(new Cat, new Dog, new Bird); // In order to modify this method, we need to update each time it's used.
        $this->petService->doStuff(); // We don't need to worry about passing in arguments since it's handled by the service container when constructing the pet service and can make changes without updating each controller that uses it.
    }
}
```

And to go further into detail, what happens if you decide `Bird` now needs an instance of `Chicken`, `Turkey`, `Dodo` in order for it to function correctly.  Now you need to again go through any traits that use `Bird` and update each to pass in an instance of each of its dependencies.

This is why it's advantageous to use the service container and providers to plan out and build your dependencies of your service classes.  It greatly increases the maintainability of your app.  It would be by far most beneficial in a very large and complicated app.

However, if your app is fairly simple, it may not be as useful and maybe even add unnecessary complexity and traits may in fact be better to use at that point if they make more sense to you.  It's not good to have your app be flexible using services when it doesn't need to be.

Comment: I like the points you try to make, but I find it hard to see how you can wire Laravel to automatically inject a role or permission.

Comment: For example I have function in Trait called doStaff(); this function needs User,  Permission and Role models. I define this function like this : doStaff(User $user, Permission $permission, Role $role), but in controller I will not pass any argument to this function.. even though I didn't pass any argument, I think laravel will automatically inject this 3 model for me inside trait function.  So if I want to inject 4-th model Post inside that function, I'll just change trait function -->  doStaff(User $user, Permission $permission, Role $role, Post $post).  so what's the problem?

Comment: @Devon Laravel has a very powerful service container (what I referred to as IoC container).  This is all described in the docs.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container

Comment: @O.Shekriladze Have you tried that?  I am fairly certain Laravel will not inject those arguments for you.  How can it at that point?  You are calling the method directly.

Comment: @user3158900 yes I'm aware, I use Laravel often.  However, Permissions and Roles may be dependent on specific context, so I'm not sure how you'd be able to configure any sort of auto-wiring on a Model instance of them.  You may want to update your example or add more details on how Laravel would know which instance to inject.

Comment: Those are just an example to get a point across.  To go into more detail about how we could theoretically setup an ACL using the service container would be getting away from my point.  I did update my answer to use different examples to make it less confusing.

Comment: @user3158900  and what if I don't pass these Cat, Dog and Bird and I instantiate them inside trait if needed?

Comment: @O.Shekriladze In a very complex app, you will eventually end up with some sort of base trait(s) which would contain all the logic for managing all the dependencies in your app.  That would essentially be your service container, except because it's been written in a trait as opposed to a traditional service container, you don't get the additional functionality that comes with having a service container.